# I'm Trying to make a link Shortener and an error comes

Tags: url, batch-file, cmd

I have an error "url is not recognized as an internal or external command" and this is my code

```
@echo off
set /p firstline=<qwe.txt
echo %firstline%
for %%a in (%firstline%) DO (
echo & set text=http://adfoc.us/api/?key=c803bc5b2f2e8ad5ccb0166d4bc898ae&url=%%a
)
echo %text% > output.txt
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

The special characters `&` within the url need to be escaped with `^` or place the special characters within a quoted string `set text="One&Two"`.  Also that echo statement is doing nothing before the set statement.

```
@echo off
set /p firstline=<qwe.txt
echo %firstline%
for %%a in (%firstline%) DO (
    set "text=http://adfoc.us/api/?key=c803bc5b2f2e8ad5ccb0166d4bc898ae^&url=%%a"
)
echo %text%>output.txt
pause
```